# MobileServiceClient error with Android project in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to build my Android project in a Xamarin.Forms solution and the following line keeps raising an exception that breaks the build.

```
client = new MobileServiceClient("backend_url");
```

This error is shown as such:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: A Microsoft Azure Mobile Services assembly for the current platform was not found. Ensure that the current project references both Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile and the following platform-specific assembly: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.
```

I saw another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589614/how-to-use-azure-mobile-services-with-xamarin-auth#24768422) saying to manually add the reference to the Android project but also a Xamarin dev said the problem was fixed after a certain update (maybe not so much). Anyone have an idea where to fix this.
I already went into the Android project> References > Browse> but couldn't find Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Ext

Comment: Hi,
how did you add the Azure Projects? Nuget? In that case ensure you have the packages installed in the android project

Comment: You need to add the Azure Mobile Client NuGet package to all the mobile app projects in the solution

Comment: Yup, I keep assuming NuGet packages for the PCL are inherited as well but that is definitely not the case. Would be nice though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derp

> You need to add the Azure Mobile Client NuGet package to all the
>   mobile app projects in the solution
>    - [Ken Tucker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1289864/ken-tucker)